# Unable to view more than 1 file

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to read a list of files from a directory and the format is field1_field2_field3.pdf. I want to explode it and populate a table and paginate it. However I've hit a bump. So far I can read all the files in a directory in this format 'name.pdf'. However, when I explode the name, only one appears. The next thing is that I don't know how to paginate the results.

This is my code

View

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $policyno; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller

```
 $this->load->helper('directory');
    $map = directory_map('./assets/data/');
    $nric = $this->session->userdata('nric');
    foreach($map as $row)
    {
        $separate = explode('_',$row);
        $data = array( 
         'firstname' => $separate[0],
         'product' => $separate[1],
         'policyno' => substr($separate[2],0,strlen($separate[2])-4)
         );

    }

    $this->load->view('includes/user/header');
    $this->load->view('user/statements',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/user/footer');
```

Please help.

Comment: Whats is the exact name of the file? Also, the easiest way of reading the file system is using recursion, unless you are absolutely sure there are no nested folders in the path you want to read.

Comment: Um..Its a list of names so name_type_number.pdf

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope. The array index  that is being sent through is the last one. Not sure how to send all through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the extension first.

**Edit:**
I didn't notice at first, but you are assigning a new array to data every time you iterate.

Try it like this:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$map = directory_map('./assets/data/');
$nric = $this->session->userdata('nric');
foreach($map as $row)
{
    $separate = explode('_',trim($row,".pdf"));
    $data['data'][] = array( 
     'firstname' => $separate[0],
     'product' => $separate[1],
     'policyno' => substr($separate[2],0,strlen($separate[2])-4)
     );

}

$this->load->view('includes/user/header');
$this->load->view('user/statements',$data);
$this->load->view('includes/user/footer');
```

For your view to work, you need to iterate the data array, like this:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $file): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $file['firstname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $file['product']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $file['policyno']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The last file is the only one showing. The first one is missing.

Comment: Um..how do I change my view? Sorry, im not very familiar with this. And if i add the [] to data, my current variables will cause an error

Comment: Oh its the same one in the question. Sorry I hope I didnt confuse you.

Comment: @JianYA My bad, i didnt' see it. I updated my answer for the view and the controller code.